# How to use select statement in a value statement

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. The log is saying that the select has a syntax error which I copied below. How do I fix this?

"Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant,a datetime constant, a missing value, +, -, MISSING, NULL, USER.

ERROR: Syntax error, statement will be ignored."

```
proc sql;
    insert into orion.test  (Fruits, Vegetables, Drinks, Meats)
        values (select a.fruit, a.veggie, a.drink, a.meat FROM work.meals AS a);
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be:

```
proc sql;
    insert into orion.test  (Fruits, Vegetables, Drinks, Meats)
        select a.fruit, a.veggie, a.drink, a.meat FROM work.meals AS a;
quit;
```

In your original `VALUES` clause you can only use constants.