# What is the difference of a statement and a clause in SAS?

Tags: sas

For example, in SAS's PROC SQL, there are two ways to insert new rows to a table:
INSERT is a statement but VALUES is a clause.
So if they are different, what is the purpose of knowing the difference between a statement and a clause?

Answer (score 3):

A clause is part of a statement.

**INSERT statement**

The `INSERT` statement can take more than one form:

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT a,b FROM table1;

INSERT INTO table VALUES ('test',100);
```

The first statement has a `SELECT` clause, the second employs a `VALUES` clause.

**SELECT statement**

`SELECT` is another form of `PROC SQL` statement, but this can contain a number of clauses:

- `SELECT`
- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `ORDER BY`

**CASE expression**

Another place where clauses are used is in a `CASE` expression, which contains a number of `WHEN-THEN` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for VALUES and SELECT clause in INSERT statement see [How to use select statement in a value statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145679/how-to-use-select-statement-in-a-value-statement/31147973#31147973) . VALUES provides a possibility to insert constants (only constants).